# How to calculate the number of hours between 2 time stamps in military time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetimeoffset

I'm trying to find the number of hours between two time stamps in SQL Server. The data is structured like this:

```
SwipeTime                                  
2019-02-01 18:53:00.740 +0000               

RequestDate
2019-02-01 18:45:52.640 -0500
```

I need to find the number of hours between SwipeTime and RequestDate so I can create buckets for different time periods. I tried: datediff(hour,a.SwipeTime,a.requestdate) as delta
This returned a value of 5, which I recognize comes from the '-0500' portion of the RequestDate time stamp. Where I get confused is in this example:

```
SwipeTime                                  
2019-01-18 12:21:47.648 +0000               

RequestDate
2019-01-17 17:46:57.380 -0500
```

In this case, SwipeTime is the following day, but `datediff(hour,a.SwipeTime,a.requestdate)` returns a value of -14. This has me stumped and I'm not sure how to get the correct number of hours between the two timestamps, which is 18 hours. Any help would be appreciated!

```
select 
    a.applicationnumber
    , a.SwipeTime
    , a.requestdate
    , datediff(hour,a.requestdate,a.SwipeTime) as delta
from swipe
```

Comment: convert them to seconds since epoch

Comment: What is the data type of the columns?

Comment: But thats the correct addition for a datetimeoffset datatpye, which is what you have. Maybe you shouldn't be stored the timezone offset if you don't want it? Or if you want to ignore it convert to a datetime which will remove the offset. But you need to think carefully about what you are storing and why.

Answer (score 0):

I would be far more inclined to do this properly i.e. transform your string data into actual `datetimeoffset` data and the you can just cast to `datetime` to ignore the timezone.

That is a more robust solution because it doesn't require knowledge of the data shape. And once you have the data in a native datatype its easier to manipulate it correctly.

```
select y.SwipeTime, y.RequestTime
  -- calculate different ignoring timezone by converting to regular datetime
  , datediff(hour, convert(datetime,y.RequestTime), convert(datetime,y.SwipeTime))
from (
  -- Incoming values
  values ('2019-01-18 12:21:47.648 +0000', '2019-01-17 17:46:57.380 -0500')
) x (SwipeTime, RequestTime)
cross apply (
  -- Convert to actual datetimeoffset datatype
  values (convert(datetimeoffset,substring(x.SwipeTime,1,27) + ':' + substring(x.SwipeTime,28,2)), convert(datetimeoffset,substring(x.RequestTime,1,27) + ':' + substring(x.RequestTime,28,2)))
) y (SwipeTime, RequestTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. After reading Dale's comment I realized I conceptually wasn't thinking about the difference between two times properly. After exploring the data, I found that it has either a 4 or 5 hour offset. To account for this, I used this query, which works:

```
CASE
    WHEN substring(a.requestdate,27,1)='5' then (datediff(hour,a.requestdate,a.SwipeTime)) + 5
    ELSE (datediff(hour,a.requestdate,a.SwipeTime)) + 4
END AS delta
```

Comment: This will only account for 4 or 5. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67409969/13198 answer will work with other offsets as well.